# CSS3 Animation only working with webkit?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, animation, webkit

I am making a CSS3 animation with a puzzle piece on my website.  The code that I am using is below.  For some reason, the animation will only work with Safari, and Chrome.  How can I get the animation to work with Firefox and Opera?  Thank you for your responses!

```
img#animation
{
length:150px;
width:150px;
position:relative;
animation:puzzle 4s
-moz-animation:puzzle 4s;
-webkit-animation:puzzle 4s;
-o-animation:puzzle 4s;
}
@keyframes puzzle
{
from {left:-400px; top:0px;}
to {left:41px; top:0px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes puzzle
{
from {left:-400px; top:0px;}
to {left:41px; top:0px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes puzzle
{
from {left:-400px; top:0px;}
to {left:40.5px; top:0px;}
}
@-o-keyframes puzzle
{
from {left:-400px; top:0px;}
to {left:41px; top:0px;}
}
```

Comment: what's `length:150px;` ?

Comment: Jc, if Zoltan's answer worked for you, do accept it so this is marked closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon in this line

```
animation:puzzle 4s;
                ---^
```

Add it and it will work - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2rwLq/2/)